# How to redirect a php file upload form to URL?

Tags: php, forms, image, file, upload

I have a working (image) file upload form, BUT currently after uploading, it opens a "blank" page stating the upload progress (e.g. "File is an image - image/jpeg.The file 01.jpg has been uploaded.").

Is it possible, after uploading, to go to URL instead of this simple message? Lets say either error.php or sent.php, so that it doesn't take the user away from the website itself.

Here's the code:

```js
<?php

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 10000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ajax-contact-form">
    Choose files:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Use PHP's `header()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with php, so my method here might be very wrong, but I did earlier try to replace the echo lines with "header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); exit;" and similar options. However, this only brings up a completely blank page.

Comment: send the user to one of your website's pages

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        @header("Location: uploads/". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]));
        @exit;
    }
```

If you want to redirect them to another website page you must use `http://` with the URL.

If it doesn't work at all, 
Try to use JavaScript redirecting code.

`<script>window.location='https://qwezxc.com/';</script>`